# Why is my HTML page not being displayed on the local host in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, django, google-app-engine

Here's my main.py file and the html file that I want to be rendered by the Jinja2 template that I am using:

main.py

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),     autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("temp.html")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

temp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#logo
{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top:5%;
 margin-left:25%;
}

div#cart
{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left:87%;
 margin-top:-2px;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id = logo><img src="logo.png" height = 60% width = 60%></div>
<div id = cart><img src="cart.jpg" height = 75 px ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I have saved the html file along with the required images in the templates folder of my app engine application directory. Also, the html file works fine when I run it on my browser. However, when I run my application using GAE, a blank screen is all I get. Why is it so? Why is my html file not getting rendered?

Comment: I expect the page is showing but the images are not. Have you actually defined any handlers in app.yaml to display your images?

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: Maybe try reading the documentation?

Comment: I created a folder named 'stylesheets' in my directory, and copied my css file inside this folder. Then I linked this file using external css definition inside my html file which was in the templates folder. This is the extra handler that I added:  - url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
However, I still get a blank screen. What else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Check that your html is actually rendering (put some text in the html file)
2. Your app.yaml file needs to include a static dir where your photos are placed.  See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python/blob/master/app.yaml for an example.
3. Reference the images using a URL appropriate to where you put the images, e.g. [image] if you put them under the "client" directory.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python

is good to look at for basic configuration.